# Divergence of tensorflow model while trying to stop batch_norm training during calibration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to stop the training of batch normalization variables during training at a given step. To do so, i wrote the following code:

```
early_training_stop = 1000
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
train_phase = tf.cond(global_step < early_training_stop, lambda: True, lambda: False)

out = tf.layers.conv2D(inputs, filters=16, kernel_size=4)
out_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(
        input_layer,
        decay=decay,
        scale=scale,
        epsilon=epsilon,
        is_training=train_phase,
        fused=True,
        data_format=self.data_format,
        scope=scope)

loss_op = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=targets, predictions=inputs) 
learning_rate = 1e-4
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
with tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
    train_op = optimizer_op.minimize(loss_op, global_step=global_step)
```

When training the network, it starts properly (batch norm variables are trained). Unfortunately, when `global_step` reach `early_training_stop`, I get the following error: `Model diverged with loss = NaN.`. How to avoid this error ? Maybe in removing batch_norm ops from training variables ? (I though doing so would do this).